# Creating a search database form with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a search for my website using PHP but every time I search for something is shows me No results found!

```
<form action="search" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>





<?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

$videosHTML = "";

$searchquery = mysqli_query("SELECT id, Name, Link, Time, Type FROM Videos WHERE Name LIKE '%$searchq%'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($searchquery);
if ($count == 0){
$videosHTML = "No results found!";
} else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchquery)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $Name = $row['Name'];
    $Link = $row['Link'];
    $Time = $row['Time'];
    $Type = $row['Type'];


    $videosHTML = '<a href="video?id='.$id.'"><div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: ' . "url('thumbnails/" . $id . ".png');" . '"><p class="title">' . $Name . '</p><p class="time">' . $Time . '</p></div></a>' . $videosHTML;

}
}
}
?>
```

It also shows me a parse error on the line of $searchquery and also on the next line $count.

I'm thinking that it's not finding anything in the $count and that's why it might show No results found.

Comment: you're not connecting to your db  in your query.

Comment: You must [connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) to a database before you can query it.

Comment: With `mysqli_query` I think you need to supply the database connection object when you query the db, like `mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )` ( if not using OO style that is )

Answer (score 1):

In light of the( perfectly valid ) comment made the original code has been completely edited in accordance with better practises. Whenever taking user input for inclusion in any sql command you must treat that as potentially damaging and use functions built into PHP to help mitigate SQL injection.

Within PHP & mySQLi you have easy access to [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which should be used in preference to embedding user supplied data directly within the sql command. Using [mysqli_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) is not sufficient to completely protect against SQL injection and should likely be ignored as it can potentially change the legitimate content (ie: complex passwords ) and render it useless.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['search'] ) ){
    
        $phrase=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'search', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED ) )
        $search='%' . $phrase . '%';
        
        $sql='select `id`,`name`,`link`,`time`,`type` from `videos` where `name` like ?';
        $stmt=$dbconn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $search );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result( $id, $name, $link, $time, $type );
        
        while( $stmt->fetch() )printf('
            <a href="video?id=%1$s">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url( thumbnails/%1$s.png )">
                    <p class="title">%2$s</p>
                    <p class="time">%3$s</p>
                    <p class="type">%4$s</p>
                </div>
            </a>', $id, $name, $time, $type );
            
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        $dbconn->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think your current-self should revisit your advice on this answer and consider an edit.  I am confident that you are better than this now.